# I am trying to open a bunch of websites that are stored in a list and each opening is delayed by 1 second

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the code:

```
import webbrowser as url
import os
import time
os.system('ipconfig /flushdns')
urllist = ['url1','url2','url3','url4','url5','url6','url7','url8','url9']
for elem in urllist:
    print(urllist)
    time.sleep(1)
```

What I want to happen is one website opening, then another one second later but I don't know how to select a certain value from a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Try this

```
urllist = ['url1','url2','url3','url4','url5','url6','url7','url8','url9']
for elem in urllist:
    # print(urllist)
    print(elem)
```

Output

```
url1
url2
url3
url4
url5
url6
url7
url8
url9
```